# Is there a maximum amount of payment that can be collected through mobile via each payment method (check, credit, ACH, cash)?

Tags: mobile, payment-processing

When using ST Payments and Payment Collections to collect a deposit on an estimate in the mobile app, is there a maximum amount that can be collected? Customer said they tried to enter a $54,000 check but received an error that it exceeded the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check processing limits are account-specific.  These would be set upon the initial onboarding of the Check/ACH processing account based upon the business financials provided.

Whenever a check returns due to a "Velocity" limit, Fintech Support receives a notification automatically and we work with the Processor to try to increase the limits for the account moving forward.